# Ascending results based on two columns mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How could I get ascending results based on two columns mysql. Like I want 1,2,3,4,5 or 1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5 but other values are on the other columns.

```
sample table
-------------
col1   col2
741     0
742     0
743     0
744     0
745     743
------------

Expected output

-------------
col1   col2
741     0
742     0
743     0
745     743
744     0
------------
```

when going through the col1 and the it find the next number on the col2 so it will add on the asc.

Comment: how that happen? 744 is not greater than 745

Comment: Will `col2` always be lower than `col1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case when in your order by clause

Try this:

```
SELECT       
FROM tablename
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        when col1 < col2 AND NOT col1 = 0 AND NOT col2 = 0 then col1
        when col1 < col2 AND col1 = 0 then col2
        when col2 < col1 AND NOT col1 = 0 AND NOT col2 = 0 then col2
        when col2 < col1 AND col2 = 0 then col1
    END DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for answering mate, but I'm getting error. @shmosel answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise this will work in all cases, but it should satisfy your example:

```
  SELECT col1, col2
    FROM test
ORDER BY IF(col2 = 0, col1, col2), col1;
```

The idea is that we're sort of merging `col2` into `col1` for sorting purposes, so the sort sees your data like this:

```
741
742
743
743  -- pulled from col2
744
```

Then the actual `col1` is used as a tiebreaker to put the mapped row second, the assumption being that `col1` will always be greater than `col2`.

Comment: Thanks @shmosel! It works perfectly. What a brain. Where could I get the documentation for this?

Comment: @VandolphReyes MySQL SELECT is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: transfered to post comment

Answer (score 0):

@shmosel. Thanks for the answer by the way it helps. But as like what you said, it's not working in all cases. It's giving different results now when col2 is having value that is already being called on the top. I'll try to explain clearly.

This is now the new table with the added values.

```
-------------
col1   col2
741     0
742     0
743     0
745     0
746     743
747     0
748     0
749     0
750     746
751     0
752     746
------------
```

And here is the result based on your first answer.

```
-------------
col1   col2
741     0
742     0
743     0
746     743
745     0
750     746
752     746
747     0
748     0
749     0
751     0
------------
```

And what I expected is this

```
-------------
col1   col2
741     0
742     0
743     0
746     743
750     746
752     746
745     0
747     0
748     0
749     0
751     0
------------
```

So since 746 (col1) has next number on the  col2, so it should those priority. I forgot to mention that col1 are unique and col2 and not. col2 are inserted based on col1. So it's like counting this. col 1 then col2. Sorry for uncleared question.